# What category of AI would a 2048 bot be considered?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have just delved into the realm of AI and from what I can tell its a very vast field of study. I am a game programmer, so AI in games is particularly interesting to me. My question is, what type of AI would a bot that can beat 2048 fall under?

I learned the basics of machine learning, but I wasn't sure if this is how you could apply machine learning. I want to know what category this falls under so I know what to research and learn to make my own bot. Also, if you don't know what 2048 is, check it out [here](https://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/).

Comment: Branching factor for this game is high, so taking simple approach, like [here](https://github.com/ovolve/2048-AI/blob/master/README.md) would be to use alpha-beta, but not all people consider MM to be AI. What do you have in mind? What types have you considered?

Comment: Rather than asking for a category, I think it would be more effective/useful to ask what AI techniques might be effective in building a bot to play 2048.

Comment: Tell me if you decide to work on it. Would be interested to look at it if you work "publicly" (e.g. sources on github). I am thinking about a Tetris bot, it also involves reinforcement

Comment: Relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342854/what-is-the-optimal-algorithm-for-the-game-2048/22389702#22389702

Answer (score 2):

I would initially say that you can classify 2048 as a MDP problem.

For this reason, I would consider looking at Reinforcement Learning (an area of Machine Learning).

Another option, however, more specific would be to look at the performance of Monte Carlo Tree Search.

There is a great discussion in StackOverflow about 2048 different approaches have been tried:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342854/what-is-the-optimal-algorithm-for-the-game-2048

Comment: This is a helpful approach to try to solve 2048, but at risk of being pedantic, it doesn't answer the question that was asked.  Those aren't categories; those are algorithms.  The question asked for what category would any solution fall under.  Nothing says those are the only algorithms that could work.